# add_widget to a widget KivyMD?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I am trying to use TwoLineIconListItem with add_widget in a for loop but I can't figure out how to add the icon. It does not take an Icon parameter because per the docs IconLeftWidget is nested like so:

```
TwoLineIconListItem:
    text: "Two-line item with avatar"
    secondary_text: "Secondary text here"

    IconLeftWidget:
        icon: "language-python"
```

I know how to do this in the KV language but how do you do it in a python for loop that populates a list. This is the closest I got but it puts the icon above the text

```
for i, z, n in zip(x[1::2], x[0::2], range(1,10)):

            self.root.ids.todays_workout.add_widget(
                IconLeftWidget(icon=f"numeric-{n}-box-multiple-outline"))

            self.root.ids.todays_workout.add_widget(
                TwoLineIconListItem(text=f"{i}", secondary_text=f"{z}"))
```

Perhaps a nested `add_widget()`? I'm not sure how to accomplish this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a second look at the docs and some help from the KivyMD support Discord Channel, I have found the solution.

You need to create a new class that inherits from the TwoLineIconListItem as such:

```
class ListWithIcon(TwoLineIconListItem):
    icon = StringProperty("string")
```

Then I created a new .kv file called listwithicon.kv with the following (notice the class names match)

```
<ListWithIcon>:

    IconLeftWidget:
        icon: root.icon
```

Finally in my main KV string(or file) I added `#: include listwithicon.kv`

These steps will allow you to add an `icon` parameter to your function. Just be sure to pass `ListWithIcon` (your new class) instead of the KivyMD class `TwoLineIconListItem`

```
for i, z, n in zip(x[1::2], x[0::2], range(1,number_workouts)):

            self.root.ids.todays_workout.add_widget(
                ListWithIcon(text=f"{i}", secondary_text=f"{z}", icon=f"numeric-{n}-box-multiple-outline"))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your nested `add_widget()` is along the right track, but you can't actually do that because `add_widget()` returns `None`. So you can do it something like this:

```
for i, z, n in zip(x[1::2], x[0::2], range(1,10)):
    icon = IconLeftWidget(icon=f"numeric-{n}-box-multiple-outline"))
    listItem = TwoLineIconListItem(text=f"{i}", secondary_text=f"{z}"))
    listItem.add_widget(icon)
    self.root.ids.todays_workout.add_widget(listItem)
```

Comment: The produced the same result as my attempt, I achieved the answer with some help from the official KivyMD support Discord channel & a second look at the documentation, I'll post the solution shortly

Comment: could you please post your Solution?